# ViewHolder on Multiple inflater

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

I have an inflater issue with viewholder on listviews. With viewholder implemented it gets wrong inflater so message is displayed wrong. (At image 10. message is not from me moreover wrong message changes whenever i scroll, i becames 7,4 or any other as if it takes inflater randomly)

I have 2 different inflater, one for their which displays their profileImage and one for me.

Here is the code :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder viewHolder; 
        if (convertView == null) {


        if(messageList.get(position).getSenderRealId() != relevantId)
        {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_detail_row_my_inflater, parent, false);
        }else{
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.message_detail_row_their_inflater, parent, false);
        }

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.messageDateText = (CustomFontTextView) findViewById(R.id.messageDateText);
        viewHolder.profileImageView = (SquareImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        viewHolder.messageBubbleLayout =  (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageBubbleLayout);
        viewHolder.messageText = (CustomFontTextView) viewHolder.messageBubbleLayout.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        viewHolder.messageHourText = (CustomFontTextView) viewHolder.messageBubbleLayout.findViewById(R.id.messageHourText);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.messageText.setText(messageList.get(position).getMessage());
        viewHolder.messageHourText.setText(Constants.hourFormat.format(messageList.get(position).getSendTime()));



        return convertView;

    }
```

And viewHolderClass :

```
static class ViewHolder {
    CustomFontTextView messageDateText;
    SquareImageView profileImageView;
    LinearLayout messageBubbleLayout;
    CustomFontTextView messageText;
    CustomFontTextView messageHourText;

}
```

Currently, I only set messageHour and messageText but all components except image are inside a linearlayout(messageBubbleLayout) which i dont think causes the problem.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using two different layouts here, you should use Android's mechanism to properly reuse convertviews.

Check out the tutorial here:

http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/06/11/making-a-multiple-view-type-adapter-with-annotations/

In your case, you have only two types of views: "my" and "their", so override `getViewTypeCount()` method to return 2, and `getItemViewType()` to return proper type based on position.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, since I was recrating on every time getView() called.